# Misunderstanding of sjoin function with geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I have an issue with the function **sjoin** of GeoPandas (0.5.1). 
In fact, when I try this function on the same GeoDataFrame, the result is a table that contains more results than I expected.

I am running this little code :

```py
gpd.sjoin(l.frame, l.frame, op='intersects', how='left')
```

The frame that I use contains:

```
id               geometry
0   LINESTRING (-44500.48827615567 888412.75133248...
1   LINESTRING (17219.37750674287 1117318.84695587...
```

And the result is :

```
   id_left                                           geometry  index_right  \
0        0  LINESTRING (-44500.48827615567 888412.75133248...            0   
0        0  LINESTRING (-44500.48827615567 888412.75133248...            1   
1        1  LINESTRING (17219.37750674287 1117318.84695587...            0   
1        1  LINESTRING (17219.37750674287 1117318.84695587...            1   
   id_right  
0         0  
0         1
```

Why don't I have only the 2 first lines in result table ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious reason would be the following - lines in dataframe intersect.

You can check that with:

```
gdf.geometry.iloc[0].intersects(gdf.geometry.iloc[1])
```

If that returns `True` the resulting dataframe just shows you that each line of the dataframe intersects with the others.

Keep in mind that each object intersects with itself.

To remove those add something like:

```
result = result.loc[result.id_left.ne(result.id_right)]
```